# Function to calculate Pi in C

Tags: c, math, pi

I'm trying to code a formula where the user inputs a number `n` to calculate `Pi` using **Pi= n^2/(n-1)(n+1)**. But for some reason the output is wrong. I don't know if my math is wrong or there's something wrong with the function.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double pi_array (int n)
{
    int i;
    double a;
    if (n%2==0)
    {
        for (i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
        {
            a=pow(n,2)/((n-1)*(n+1));
        }
    }
    return a;
}

double pi_value (int n)
{
    int i;
    double pi;
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
       pi=pi_array(n);
    }
    return pi;
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf ("%lf\n", pi_value(n));
}
```

Comment: You need to think about your loops more. `pi=pi_array(n);` doesn't depend on `i`, so you're just doing the same computation `n` times, overwriting `pi` each time - remove the loop and the effect is the same. The other loop has the same issue.

Comment: `a=pow(n,2)/((n-1)*(n+1));` is suspicious.  Do you want `a += pow(n,2)/((n-1)*(n+1));`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no the numbers dont add up. For example when I put 2 it returns 4

Comment: you need to explain your mathematics a little more clear. how will you receive 4 when your input is 2?

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Mat pointed out, in this part of your code:

```
   for (i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
    {
        a=pow(n,2)/((n-1)*(n+1));
    }
```

It is doing the same computation again and again because `n` does not change its value. The answer `pow(n,2)/((n-1)*(n+1))` remains the same even for all the iterations.

Also, on a side note, what formula are you using to calculate your answer? If you put `n = 4`, you get the value as 16/15 which equals 1.0667. For `n = 5`, the asnwer is 1.041667. They are clearly not equal to `pi`. I think thew formula might be wrong itself. You could post the question about the formula on [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) to get an idea of what the exact formula is, and then implement it in C later :).

Best.